# Nvidia errors overnight

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So overnight I had issues with CUDA/Nvidia. If I run `nvidia-smi` on my VM, I get this error `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Comment: You can open an issue in the [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com) to get attention of your stated NVIDIA-SMI issue.

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1000340/cuda-setup-and-installation/-quot-nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldn-t-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-quot-ubuntu-16-04/2

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below workaround and check whether it resolves the issue or not.

This sample solution is done on Google Compute Engine having *NVIDIA Tesla K80* and *Ubuntu 16.04*. Change might be required according to the OS.

#### Steps

1. `curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i ./cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install cuda-8-0 cuda-drivers=384.111-1 -y`

**To check**

```
nvidia-smi
```

Hope this helps.